# Rust generics on functions

Tags: generics, rust, serde

I'm refactoring some Rust code (see below) to parse various configuration files (in JSON) using the `serde` crate.

Therefore I have 2 structs: `CfgFileWebServer` & `CfgFileFtpServer` implementing `Serialize` & `Deserialize` traits.

For both structs I have separate parsing functions. As the parsing code is nearly identical I'd like to rewrite it using generics to get:

```
parse_cfg_file::<CfgFileWebServer>(path: &Path) -> Result<(), Error> { ... }
parse_cfg_file::<CfgFileFtpServer>(path: &Path) -> Result<(), Error> { ... }
```

However I don't know how to make the deserialized variable `p` (`serde_json::from_str`) generic. I tried following:

```
fn parse_cfg_file<T: Deserialize>(path: &Path) 
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected lifetime parameter
```

What lifetime should I pass to the trait?

Here is current implementation without generics:

```
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

use serde_json::Error;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct CfgFileWebServer {
    name: String,
    /* fields omitted */
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct CfgFileFtpServer {
    name: String,
    /* fields omitted */
}

fn parse_web_server() -> Result<(), Error> {

    let data = r#"{
                    "name": "WebServer",
                  }"#;

    let p: CfgFileWebServer = serde_json::from_str(data)?;

    Ok(())
}

fn parse_ftp_server() -> Result<(), Error> {

    let data = r#"{
                    "name": "FTPServer",
                  }"#;

    let p: CfgFileFtpServer = serde_json::from_str(data)?;

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    parse_web_server().unwrap();
    parse_ftp_server().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just adding a lifetime parameter, e.g. `fn parse_cfg_file<'a, T: Deserialize<'a>>(path: &Path) { ... }`?

Comment: @ljedrz Thanks. This is what I was looking for.